# Anyone Migrated from Snowflake to Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, database-migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Anyone ever tried migrating from Snowflake to Redshift? Or things to consider if you have been using Snowflake.

Need to understand the implications as providing options paper.

Thanks 
P

Answer (score 0):

This is a very wide topic and consideration depends on the usage, volume of data, availability, SLA etc. For migration to Redshift I recommend to review white papers and options in AWS Database Migration Service.

Answer (score -3):

This is a very helpful guide on how to migrate data from snowflake to redshift cost effectively. Basically you can orchestrate migration using Glue Workflow and automate generation of COPY commands both in SF and RS.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-from-snowflake-to-amazon-redshift-using-aws-glue-python-shell/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)